# Parse error expected identifier or '('

Tags: ios

Forgive the Beginner question, but I copied and pasted from the apple developer site, changed the names, and it gives me a parse error. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    AddgameViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController]
    gametem *item = source.gameitem
    if (item != nil) {
        [self.gameitems addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? When I add a semicolon after segue like it asks me to, I get that parse error.

Comment: The convention is that method and variable names start with a lowercase letter and class names begin with an uppercase letter. In Objective-C statements **must** be terminated with a ";", this tells the compiler that the statement is complete. Get a book on the "C" language and study it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:  (added two semicolons and changed gametem to gameitem)

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    AddgameViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    gameitem *item = source.gameitem;
    if (item != nil) {
       [self.gameitems addObject:item];
       [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```